# Backbone Model fetched from Lithium controller is not loaded properly in bb Model

Tags: php, jquery, backbone.js, php-mongodb, lithium

I'm using backbone.js and Lithium.
I'm fetching a model from the server by passing in a _id that is received as a hidden parameter on the page.

The database MongoDB has stored the data correctly and can be viewed from console as:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50bb82694fbe3de417000001"), "holiday_name" : "SHREE15", "description": "", "star_rating" : "3", "holiday_type" : "family", "rooms" : "1", "adults" : "2", "child" :"0", "emails" : "" }
```

The Lithium Model class is so:

```
class Holidays extends \lithium\data\Model {
public $validates = array(
        'holiday_name' => array(
                array(
                        'notEmpty',
                        'required' => true,
                        'message' => 'Please key-in a holiday name! (eg. Family trip for summer holidays)'
                ))); }
```

The backbone Holiday model is so:

```
    window.app.IHoliday = Backbone.Model.extend({       
    urlRoot: HOLIDAY_URL,
    idAttribute: "_id",
    id: "_id",
    // Default attributes for the holiday.
    defaults: {
    },

    // Ensure that each todo created has `title`.
    initialize: function(props) {

    },
```

The code for backbone/fetch is:

```
var Holiday = new window.app.IHoliday({ _id: holiday_id });
        Holiday.fetch(
                {
                    success: function(){
                        alert('Holiday fetched:' + JSON.stringify(Holiday));
                        console.log('HOLIDAY Fetched: \n' + JSON.stringify(Holiday));
                        console.log('Holiday name:' + Holiday.get('holiday_name'));
                    }
                }               
           );
```

Lithium Controller Code is:

```
public function load($holiday_id)
{
    $Holiday = Holidays::find($holiday_id);
    return compact('Holiday');
}
```

PROBLEM:
The output of the backbone model fetched from server is as below and the Holiday model is not correctly 'formed' when data returns into backbone Model:

```
    HOLIDAY Fetched: 
{"_id":"50bb82694fbe3de417000001","Holiday":{"_id":"50bb82694fbe3de417000001","holiday_name":"SHREE15","description":"","star_rating":"3","holiday_type":"family","rooms":"1","adults":"2","child":"0","emails":""}}

iplann...view.js (line 68)

Holiday name:undefined
```

Clearly there is some issue when the data is passed/translated from Lithium and loaded up as a model into backbone Holiday model. Is there something very obviously wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Backbone expects the model data at the root of the response. You are putting it under the "Holiday" key. In your controller, try `return $Holiday->to("array");`. That should return it as Backbone expects. Alternately, you can override your Backbone model's `parse()` method.